# No signature of method: archives.internal.DefaultManifest.srcFile()

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to setUp my first gradle project with android studio:
I am getting the following error, which does not make any sense to me since 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' is a string.

> Error:(23, 0) No signature of method:
>   org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest.srcFile() is
>   applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
>   [app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml]

The gradle build script looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.2'
        classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.4'
        classpath "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile("app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    }
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/res')
    }
}

configurations {
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/release")
    unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    unitTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2'
}

task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
}
check.dependsOn unitTest
```

Thanks for any help.

Torsten

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that either there is no method named `srcFile` on `sourceSets.main.manifest`, or it doesn't accept a string as argument. (Often it's the former.) I think that what you are trying to configure here is `android { sourceSets { ... } }`, not `sourceSets { ... }`.